# Annoying White Bar at the Top of HTML/CSS webpage

Tags: html, css

I have some HTML and CSS code for a webpage I am building. I finally figured out how to do the slideshow, but now I have this annoying white bar at the top of my home page (above the slideshow) that I can't get rid of.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>R. J. Farah Engineering</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="rjfe.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="box fade-in logo">
            <img src="../rjfe/logo.png" style="width:270px;height:128px;">
        </div>
        <div class="menu_box fade-in menu"> 
        <div id="menu">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="rjfe.html">home</a></li>
                <li><a href="about.html">about</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">work</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">contact us</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        </div>
        <ul class="cb-slideshow">
            <li>
                <span>Image 01</span>
                <div>
                    <h3></h3>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <span>Image 02</span>
                <div>
                    <h3></h3>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <span>Image 03</span>
                <div>
                    <h3></h3>
                </div>
            </li>
        </body>
</html>
```

And my CSS:

```
@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn { from { opacity:0; } to { opacity:1; } }
@-moz-keyframes fadeIn { from { opacity:0; } to { opacity:1; } }
@keyframes fadeIn { from { opacity:0; } to { opacity:1; } }

.fade-in {
    opacity:0;  /* make things invisible upon start */
    -webkit-animation:fadeIn ease-in 1;  /* call our keyframe named fadeIn, use animattion ease-in and repeat it only 1 time */
    -moz-animation:fadeIn ease-in 1;
    animation:fadeIn ease-in 1;

    -webkit-animation-fill-mode:forwards;  /* this makes sure that after animation is done we remain at the last keyframe value (opacity: 1)*/
    -moz-animation-fill-mode:forwards;
    animation-fill-mode:forwards;

    -webkit-animation-duration:1s;
    -moz-animation-duration:1s;
    animation-duration:1s;
}

.box {
    width: 270px;
    height: 128px;
    position: absolute; bottom: 0px; right: 0px;
    margin: 10px;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    background: transparent;
}
.fade-in.logo {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.5s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 0.5s;
    animation-delay: 0.5s;
}
.menu_box {
    width: 270/2px;
    height: 128/4px;
    position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px;
    margin: 10px;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    background: transparent;
}
.fade-in.menu {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.5s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 0.5s;
    animation-delay: 0.5s;
}

/*Menus*/
#menu ul
{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    list-style-type: none;
    list-style: none;
    z-index: 0;
}

#menu li
{
    list-style-type: none;
    z-index: 0;
}

#menu a
{
    display: block;
    width: 5em;
    color: black;
    background-color: transparent;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 0;
}

#menu a:hover
{
    background-color: #6666AA;
    z-index: 0;
}
#menu li
{
    list-style-type: none;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 0.5em;
    z-index: 0;
}
.cb-slideshow,
.cb-slideshow:after { 
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: -9999; 
}
.cb-slideshow:after { 
    content: '';
    background: transparent url(../images/pattern.png) repeat top left; 
}
.cb-slideshow li span { 
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    color: transparent;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-repeat: none;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 0;
    animation: imageAnimation 18s linear infinite 0s; 
}
.cb-slideshow li div { 
    z-index: 1000;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 30px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    opacity: 0;
    color: #fff;
    animation: titleAnimation 18s linear infinite 0s; 
}
.cb-slideshow li div h4 { 
    font-family: 'BebasNeueRegular', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 100px;
    padding: 0;
    line-height: 200px; 
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(1) span { 
    background-image: url(../rjfe3/img1.jpg) 
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(2) span { 
    background-image: url(../rjfe3/img2.jpg);
    animation-delay: 6s; 
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(3) span { 
    background-image: url(../rjfe3/img3.jpg);
    animation-delay: 12s; 
}
@keyframes imageAnimation { 
    0% { opacity: 0; animation-timing-function: ease-in; }
    8% { opacity: 1; animation-timing-function: ease-out; }
    17% { opacity: 1 }
    25% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}
@keyframes titleAnimation { 
    0% { opacity: 0 }
    8% { opacity: 1 }
    17% { opacity: 1 }
    19% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}
@keyframes fadey {
    0% { opacity: 0; }
    15% { opacity: 1; }
    85% { opacity: 1; }
    100% { opacity: 0; }
}
figure#slideshow {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
}
figure#slideshow img {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0; top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    opacity: 0;
}
figure#slideshow img:first-child { 
    position: relative;
}
```

I have tried adjusting the position of the slideshow on the page because frankly that is all I can think to do...I have no idea what might be causing this.

This *still* isn't up, but here is a screenshot of the white bar in action!:

https://plus.google.com/u/0/+JosephFarahthefinalfrontier/posts/Vub3imwq1oq?pid=6193420991011414498&oid=105312277509825242261

Sorry it looks horrid--I don't have actual pictures yet, just filler, no real logo.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: @PHPglue im going to try that now. if it works, i will post it as "answering my own question" and credit you. thanks so much!!!!

Comment: @PHPglue sorry, didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `ul` containing the slideshow still has the default top margin. Removing it should solve it.

```
.cb-slideshow
    margin-top:0;
}
```

Comment: your fix works, for future programmers I have marked it as correct. However, when I add this, my menu becomes unclickable and fades away when the slideshow fades in. Thoughts?

Comment: @silentphoenix have you looked at my solution?

Comment: @shunya i have, (sorry, I just saw it now XD) and it causes the same problem. the menu becomes unusable.

Comment: yes i just noticed now it fixes one problem but creates a new one

Comment: @silentphoenix The menu still functions for me. I only see the clicking and fading problem when shunya's solution is applied.

Comment: @shunya Tree- hmmmm i will look into it. Thanks for your help though, and you too shunya!! my slideshow now works :D have a nice night XD

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is remove the comma when listing more than one class in css and thats it.

This is where your problem lies change this

```
.cb-slideshow,
.cb-slideshow:after { 
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: -9999; 
}
```

to:

```
.cb-slideshow .cb-slideshow:after { 
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: -9999; 
}
```

your problem is solved.

```
@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn { from { opacity:0; } to { opacity:1; } }
@-moz-keyframes fadeIn { from { opacity:0; } to { opacity:1; } }
@keyframes fadeIn { from { opacity:0; } to { opacity:1; } }

.fade-in {
    opacity:0;  /* make things invisible upon start */
    -webkit-animation:fadeIn ease-in 1;  /* call our keyframe named fadeIn, use animattion ease-in and repeat it only 1 time */
    -moz-animation:fadeIn ease-in 1;
    animation:fadeIn ease-in 1;

    -webkit-animation-fill-mode:forwards;  /* this makes sure that after animation is done we remain at the last keyframe value (opacity: 1)*/
    -moz-animation-fill-mode:forwards;
    animation-fill-mode:forwards;

    -webkit-animation-duration:1s;
    -moz-animation-duration:1s;
    animation-duration:1s;
}

.box {
    width: 270px;
    height: 128px;
    position: absolute; bottom: 0px; right: 0px;
    float: top;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    background: transparent;
}
.fade-in.logo {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.5s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 0.5s;
    animation-delay: 0.5s;
}
.menu_box {
    width: 270/2px;
    height: 128/4px;
    position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px;

    float: left;
    float: top;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    background: transparent;
}
.fade-in.menu {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.5s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 0.5s;
    animation-delay: 0.5s;
}

.menu_box .fade-in .menu #menu ul li{ 
    background-color: transparent;
 }

/*Menus*/
#menu ul
{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    list-style-type: none;
    list-style: none;
    z-index: 0;
    background: transparent;
}

#menu li
{

    list-style-type: none;
    z-index: 0;
}

#menu a
{
    display: block;
    width: 5em;
    color: black;

    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 0;
}

#menu a:hover
{
    background-color: #6666AA;
    z-index: 0;
}
#menu li
{
    list-style-type: none;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 0.5em;
    z-index: 0;
}
.cb-slideshow .cb-slideshow:after { 
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: -9999; 
}
.cb-slideshow:after { 
    content: '';
    background: transparent url(../images/annoying_white_bar.png) repeat top left; 
}
.cb-slideshow li span { 
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    color: transparent;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-repeat: none;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 0;
    animation: imageAnimation 18s linear infinite 0s; 
}
.cb-slideshow li div { 
    z-index: 1000;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 30px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    opacity: 0;
    color: #fff;
    animation: titleAnimation 18s linear infinite 0s; 
}
.cb-slideshow li div h4 { 
    font-family: 'BebasNeueRegular', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 100px;
    padding: 0;
    line-height: 200px; 
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(1) span { 
    background-image: url(./annoying_white_bar.png) 
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(2) span { 
    background-image: url(./annoying_white_bar.png);
    animation-delay: 6s; 
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(3) span { 
    background-image: url(./annoying_white_bar.png);
    animation-delay: 12s; 
}
@keyframes imageAnimation { 
    0% { opacity: 0; animation-timing-function: ease-in; }
    8% { opacity: 1; animation-timing-function: ease-out; }
    17% { opacity: 1 }
    25% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}
@keyframes titleAnimation { 
    0% { opacity: 0 }
    8% { opacity: 1 }
    17% { opacity: 1 }
    19% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}
@keyframes fadey {
    0% { opacity: 0; }
    15% { opacity: 1; }
    85% { opacity: 1; }
    100% { opacity: 0; }
}
figure#slideshow {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
}
figure#slideshow img {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0; top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    opacity: 0;
}
figure#slideshow img:first-child { 
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Assuming you mean applying the same properties to multiple classes, that's incorrect. That's what the comma is for. Removing the comma means you're expecting the second class to be a child of the first class. http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#grouping.

Comment: yes @TreeTree you are correct. But removing the comma was removing the whitebar on top but as you said its not the correct way of doing it.

Answer (score -2):

You have

```
<div class="box fade-in logo">
    <img src="../rjfe/logo.png" style="width:270px;height:128px;">
</div>
```

But it should look like

```
<div class="box-fade-in-logo">
    <img src="../rjfe/logo.png" style="width:270px;height:128px;">
</div>
```

The class and id should always be one work or multiple words with dashes or underscores. Try this. Hopefully it works

Comment: That's only true for the id attribute. You use spaces to denote multiple class names for the class attribute.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification I'll for sure remember that one.